# (python) Argument 'x' has incorrect type

Tags: python, cupy

My goal is to try Cupy.
Codes are located [here](https://github.com/moisutsu/make-deep-learning-from-zero-2).

When I execute 'train_custom_loop.py' in the ch1 folder.
This error is encountered.

Argument 'x' has incorrect type (expected cupy.core.core.ndarray, got numpy.ndarray)

[image]

Which part of the files should be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a `cupy.core.core.ndarray` but a `numpy.ndarray`.